# Default object as function param

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if I can do something like this:
Create a function with an object as parameter that have default properties.
If I call the function with an object with some property, that should be overwrited, but if property is not defined the value is the default value

```
function foo( args={'param1':'val1', 'param2':'val2', 'param3':'val3'} ){
   console.log(args)
}


foo() // {'param1':'val1', 'param2':'val2', 'param3':'val3'}

foo({'param2':'newValue'}) //{'param1':'val1', 'param2':'newValue', 'param3':'val3'}
```

It's possible to do this somehow? Or I have to do programmatically checking if args passed have any param, like this:

```
function foo( args={} ){
  if( !args.param1 ){
    args.param1 = 'val1'
  }
  if( !args.param2 ){
    args.param2 = 'val2'
  }
  if( !args.param3 ){
    args.param3 = 'val3'
  }
  console.log(args)
}
```

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). Check specifically _Setting a function parameter's default value_.

Comment: You could try `({ param1 = "val1", param2 = "val2", param3 = "val3" } = {})` if you don’t need `args` itself.

Comment: Maybe create an object called `defaultValues` and then inside function, first line can be `args = Object.assign({}, defaultValues, args)`

Comment: I didn't get your exact question. can you be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function foo({param1 = 'val1', param2 = 'val2', param3 = 'val3'}) {
    
    console.log(`parm1: ${param1},   parm2: ${param2},    parm3: ${param3}`)
    
    }
    
    foo({}) ;
    foo({param2: 'newValue'});
```